# Vue.js v-for not working

Tags: html, vue.js, v-for

I'm trying Vue.js out but I am running into a problem. I am following a tutorial over at Laracasts but my v-for isn't working.

HTML:

```
<div id="root">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="name in names" v-text="name"></li>
  </ul>

  <input type="text" v-model="newName">
  <button @click="addName">Add Name</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        newName: '',
      names: ['John', 'Mike']
    }
    methods: {
        addName() {
        this.names.push(this.newName);
        this.newName = '';
      }
    }
})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4pb1f4uq/

If it helps, the link to the Laracast with episode:
https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/4?autoplay=true

Comment: It may help if you read the output if your compiler or even in you console. It would show you that you've forgotten to place a comma after defining the data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the comma after the `data` object:

```
data: {
  newName: '',
  names: ['John', 'Mike']
},  // comma here
```

Comment: Well, this works within my JSfiddle, but not my own site... this is really wierd.

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple syntax error - a comma is missing between the "data" and "methods" objects:

```
data: {
  newName: '',
  names: ['John', 'Mike']
}, //this comma was missing
```

This version of your fiddle adds it, and shows it working: https://jsfiddle.net/4pb1f4uq/1/

You can detect this kind of thing easily yourself by checking for errors in your browser's console (press F12). It will highlight the syntax error and usually you can click on the error and be taken to the offending line of code.

Answer (score 0):

v-for was not working for me, for dynamically added elements in object. Turned out there some reactivity issue. And element to array should be added like this

```
this.$set(this.files, key, file)
```