# Why can't I get a basic example of working v-for in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get just a simple hello world for `v-for`. I've googled this for an hour and found various other posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490522/vue-js-v-for-not-working) to no use.

My HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in history">
        {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

My JS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        history: [
            'red','green','blue'
        ],
    },
});
```

My Output:
`{{ item }}`

[image: Screenshot of output]

Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and why I can't get this bare-bones example working. I've tried using arrays and objects, looping using the key attribute, and several other things.

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

EDIT: apologise for the awful title; I had to change it 13 times before SO stopped yelling at me...

EDIT 2: I have the app defined containing the entire body of HTML: `<div id="app">`, thank you for the answers though : )

EDIT 3: Resolved, I must've had a div tag closed prematurely; commenting it out fixed the code. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I've got the CDN working correctly and the app set up otherwise, I just can't get `v-for` working. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probably** you don't define the id `app` in the HTML section. Here is the working code.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    history: [
      'red', 'green', 'blue'
    ],
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<ul id='app'>
  <li v-for="item in history">
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have the app defined like so: `<div id="app">`, containing all other code including my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "#app" id in your code like this

```
<ul id="app">
    <li v-for="item in history">
        {{ item }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have the app defined like so: `<div id="app">`, containing all other code including my HTML.